# How can I select an element with jQuery by matching a partial attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For example, I want to match all elements that have "data-foo" within any of their attributes:

```
<a data-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Matched</a>
<a data-foo-bar="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>
<a data-foo-bar-baz="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>

<a data-bar-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Not Matched</a>
```

I could easily loop through all of the elements and check myself but I wasn't sure if jQuery supported this type of selector.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @AlienArrays - The OP edited his original code and fixed it.

Comment: Look into `:contains()` https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: I set up an answer for you to match any `a` element that has an attribute in which contains a string of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this fiddle...a little out there but maybe you could work off this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85HyP/2/)

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var isItMe = 0;
        $(element[0].attributes).each(function() {
             if(this.nodeName.indexOf("data-bar") >= 0){
                isItMe = 1;
             }
        });
    if(isItMe == 1){
        $(this).css({"color" : "red"});  
    }
});
```

Comment: Haha this is perfect. This does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Satpal's answer is pretty good (I like that the selector is restricted to only `<a>` elements; that will be a little faster than searching the whole DOM).

I would like to suggest, though, that you use multiple data attributes.  For example:

```
<a data-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Matched</a>
<a data-foo="abc" data-foo-bar="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>
<a data-foo="abc" data-foo-bar-baz="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>

<a data-bar-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Not Matched</a>
```

Or classes:

```
<a class="foo" data-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Matched</a>
<a class="foo" data-foo-bar="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>
<a class="foo" data-foo-bar-baz="abc" href="#">I'm Matched Too</a>

<a data-bar-foo="abc" href="#">I'm Not Matched</a>
```

In in this way, you can match one one thing (either `data-foo` or class `foo`), and get the specificity you need as well.

Comment: I know I could easily add a class but that defeats the purpose of my question. I have no problem selecting these elements, I just want to select by a partial attribute name.

Comment: (nod)  I get it, but there's no way I know of to do that, so I'm just suggesting rejiggering your architecture a bit to provide some generic AND specific info.  That is, "this thing is a foo, but it is more specifically a foo-bar".  Kind of like the difference between an ID (specific) and a class (generic).

Comment: Dayumn, that's what I expected. Thank you for trying to slim it down for me!