# Target all data attributes that starts with

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is it possible to target all the `data-attributes` within an element that starts with `data-am`? The thing is that the `.container` can contain different types of `data-attributes`. Something like this below.

**Note**, I'm trying to target the data element itself, not one that contains value.

```
<div class="container">
  <div data-am-content>...</div>
</div>

.container {
    [data-am-*] {
         ...
    }
}
```

I know about targeting with a value

```
<div class="container">
   <div data-am-content="value">...</div>
</div>

.container {
   [data-am-content~="value"] {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: No, there is only an attribute value contains selector and not an attribute name contains selector.

Comment: No css solution, but there's a js solution if you're interested?

Comment: I'm trying to keep it clean with css, it's ok I'll redo my hmtl a bit. Thanks for answers @Chris

Comment: @Dejan.S. Sure thing. It seems like you were trying to use attribute names as values, by essentially having different `data-am-....` properties. It would be better to have something like `data-am-type="type"` or similar, and just change the value instead.

Answer (score 0):

create more classes for your div elements and refer to them

```
<div class="container am-foo am-bar"></div>
```

you can refer to them in css as either

```
.container
.am-foo
.am-bar
```

Does not have to be on container just add classes to element

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no way to select partial data attribute however you can style for every possible data attributes separately like

```
[data-rm-content] {
    /* Some Styles */
}
[data-rm-type] {
    /* Some Styles */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0a29rxu/3/

Edit: You can easily do with javascript see this Question [How can I select an element with jQuery by matching a partial attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651071/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-jquery-by-matching-a-partial-attribute)